# How to get parameter in to python script from Jenkins

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins

I want to make a script that takes a parameter from Jenkins, if Parameter is not provided from Jenkins then it run with default parameter that is defined in Script

Answer (score 0):

You can use try/except/else in your python script; it will first look for the env variable (as in Jenkins); if it doesn't find that it will use the one from script

```
try:
    authKey = os.environ['AUTH_KEY']
except KeyError:
    print("INFO: Key not defined in Jenkins using value from script")
else:
    authKey = 'mySecretKey'
```

In your Jenkinsfile; you can define that Env variable as

```
environment {
        AUTH_KEY = 'mySecretKeyFromJenkins'
    }
```